# How do I convert a list of strings into dict where only a certain type at an unknown index can become the keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings that looks, like this:

```
myList = [
  "this 1 is my string",
  "a nice 2 string",
  "string is 3 so nice"
]
```

I'd like to convert this string into a `dict` that also looks, like this:

```
{
  "1": "this is my string",
  "2": "a nice string",
  "3": "string is so nice"
}
```

I don't know how to do this.

Only the integer can become the key but everything else must become the value, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this without installing any external dependencies is by using the `findall` method from the `re` module.

```
from re import findall

def list_to_dict(lst):
  result = {}
  for value in lst:
    match = findall(r"\d", value)
    if len(match) > 0:
      result[match[0]] = value.replace(match[0], "").replace("  ", " ")
  return result
```

If you wanted to, you could replace the `0` index with another index, although you should only do this if you are certain you know where the integer's index is.

Then using your list:

```
my_list = [
  "this 1 is my string",
  "a nice 2 string",
  "string is 3 so nice"
]
```

You'd call the function, like this:

```
print(list_to_dict(my_list))
```

Which should output this `dict`:

```
{'1': 'this is my string', '2': 'a nice string', '3': 'string is so nice'}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiple numbers in a line, it will take the `first number` as the `key` for the `dict`,

```
>>> for line in myList:
...   match = re.search(r'\d+',line)
...   if match:
...     num = match.group()
...     newline = line.partition(num) # control over the partition
...     newline = newline[0].strip() + ' '.join(newline[2:])
...     d[num] = newline
... 
>>> 
>>> d
{'1': 'this is my string', '3': 'string is so nice', '2': 'a nice string'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

myDict = {}

for element in myList:
    # Find number using regex.
    key = re.findall(r'\d+', element)[0]
    # Get index of number.
    index = element.index(key)
    # Create new string with index and trailing space removed.
    new_element = element[:index] + element[index + 2:]
    # Add to dict.
    myDict[key] = new_element
```